# scala: operation overload and implicit conversion clarification

Tags: scala

Here is a code sample. Not sure why I am getting error when using multiplication.
Should I add implicit conversion to Int ? Sure the answer is simple!!
Thanks

```
    class Fraction(val x:Int, val y:Int)    
    {               
        def X = x
        def Y = y

        implicit def int2Fraction(n: Int) = Fraction(n, 1)
        def *(that: Fraction) : Fraction = new Fraction(that.X * X, that.Y * Y)
    }

    object Fraction {
        def apply(x: Int, y: Int) = new Fraction(x, y)
    }

    val x : Int = 3 
    val result = x * Fraction(4, 5)
    println( result.X )
```

[image]

Comment: Updated. Just refresh page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an implicit conversion to take place, it needs to be in scope. Try taking it outside the class like this:

```
implicit def int2Fraction(n: Int) = Fraction(n, 1)

class Fraction(val x:Int, val y:Int)
{
    def X = x
    def Y = y


    def *(that: Fraction) : Fraction = new Fraction(that.X * X, that.Y * Y)
}

object Fraction {
    def apply(x: Int, y: Int) = new Fraction(x, y)
}
```

You can also put it inside the companion object; the compiler searches there automatically.

Comment: Correct answer as well. It does make sense to keep conversion outside of class definition. Is there are a reason why implicits not restricted by scope of singleton related ?

Comment: Because you can use different implicit conversions for different scopes/contexts. You may want to interpret the same object in different ways given the scope (for whatever reason), and then you can import the proper conversion in each scope.

Answer (score 5):

Your implicit conversion function is a member of the Fraction class - so it can't be called without an instance of `Fraction`. If you move it to the `object`, it would work as expected:

```
object Fraction {
    def apply(x: Int, y: Int) = new Fraction(x, y)
    implicit def int2Fraction(n: Int) = Fraction(n, 1)
}
```

Comment: Oh .. I see, That the actual answer. Its very obvious by the way!