# How to avoid "error: overloaded method ... with alternatives:"

Tags: scala

How do I define foo so that it works with any type that has a method math.max? The error states that max cannot be applied to (A,A). Well if A happens to be any of the types mentioned in the error then it can be and that is what I want. Isn't that the whole point of polymorphic type parameters? I even tried foo[A <: Numeric] but got same error.

```
scala> def foo[A](a: A, b: A) = math.max(a,b)
<console>:9: error: overloaded method value max with alternatives:
(x: Double,y: Double)Double <and>
(x: Float,y: Float)Float <and>
(x: Long,y: Long)Long <and>
(x: Int,y: Int)Int
 cannot be applied to (A, A)
       def foo[A](a: A, b: A) = math.max(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you would want to do this. math.max works just fine without wrapping it into anything, but if you absolutely must then the solution will look something like this

```
   def foo[A](a:A,b:A)(implicit c:Numeric[A]) = c.max(a,b)
   foo(1,2) //2 
   foo('a',4l) //97 
   foo('g',"1") //  error: could not find implicit value for parameter c: Numeric[Any]
```

and so on...

Comment: Of course your right. To ask my question I just needed a function that had some type requirement in it's body to represent my actual use case. Please help me understand your solution. You added a 2nd parameter list to foo in order to define an implicit parameter c that is of type Numeric[A]. then you use c in the def body to access the parameters from the first parameter list. Why does that work? It

Comment: Your use of implicit does exactly what I wanted but I don't quite understand why it works. Can you refer me to further explanation on how you used implicit as you did. It's different for how @PavelOliynyk used them.

Comment: It boils down to curried functions. For example you can rewrite a simple function like `add(a:Int,b:Int):Int = a + b` as `add(a:Int)(b:Int) = a + b`, then partially apply it to create new function `add5 = add(5)_ `, then use it like this `add5(2) //7`. You can also do this `def addImplicit(a:Int)(implicit b:Int)`. The implicit keyword tells compiler to search implicit scope for a value of specific  type. Examples `addImplicit(5) // compiler error - implciti value for Int not found`, `implicit val b = 5; addImplicit(5) // 10` . Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I did ask the same question yesterday.
You will need to implement implicit conversion !
See link below. Hope this would help.

[scala: operation overload and implicit conversion clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016815/scala-operation-overload-and-implicit-conversion-clarification)